# angularJS wrong key in repeater

Tags: javascript, angularjs, repeater, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm have data:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
  0: Object
    $$hashKey: "007"
    amount: "123111"
    name: "test"
    number: "5"
    position: "ttt"
  1: Object
    $$hashKey: "006"
    amount: "123111"
    name: "test4"
    number: "4"
    position: "поз"
  2: Object
    $$hashKey: "005"
    amount: "34555"
    name: "еее"
    number: "1"
    position: "вапвап"
```

and i'm have repeater in html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, player) in players | orderBy:'number'">
    <td>{{key}} - {{player.number}}</td>
    <td>{{player.name}}</td>
    <td>{{player.position}}</td>
    <td>{{player.amount}}</td>
    <td>
        <button ng-click="edit(key)" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
        <button ng-click="delete(key)" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></span></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I need to get keys from data of the current element in repeater, but the key I get the value of the order.

```
0 - 1   еее вапвап  34555     
1 - 4   test4   поз 123111    
2 - 5   test    ttt 123111
```

but I need:

```
2 - 1   еее вапвап  34555     
1 - 4   test4   поз 123111    
0 - 5   test    ttt 123111
```

Comment: Where is `key` coming from?  It isn't defined in the object structure.

Comment: Why not just `edit(player)` ?

Comment: Thanks! `edit(player)` it's too good for me

Answer (score 0):

You can't. The order of the list values change, which means you get new values for each index before watching it using ng-repeat. You should set the index as a property of the player. Then use that property instead.

```
for(var i in players) {
    players[i].index = i;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's problem.
these data are connected directly to a remote repository and change them in scope I will change the remote data, can I get some way to correct key? such as a function or even once - without changing the data structure?

Comment: I'm think i'm can use $$hashKey property (this unique) - for search key in players array for current player inside ng-repeat. 
Unfortunately does not good for me to change the data structure.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.getRealId = function(hashKey) {
    for (var i in $scope.players) {
        if ($scope.players[i].$$hashKey === hashKey) {
            return i;
        }
    }
};
```

and inside ng-repeat:

```
{{getRealId(player.$$hashKey)}}
```

or

```
<button ng-click="edit(getRealId(player.$$hashKey))" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>
```